# How to remove air from the fuel line in a MK2 Seat Leon TDi

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-line, seat-cars, seat-leon

I have just changed two of the fuel hose (white and blue tipped ones) that lead to the fuel pump. The reason I changed them was because one of them was split and slowly leaking fuel.

I have came out a drive in it and it is choking at times. Am I right in saying that there could be air in my fuel line?

If so, how do I get this out? My tools are basic, so I am concerned this could be a mechanics job.

Is there a possibility it could work itself out naturally? I've just driven 4.5miles and parked in a layby to post this message.

I have a Seat Leon 2008 FR TDi.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work itself out. The lines you showed us before are the low pressure lines coming to/from the fuel tank. Any air in these should work itself out fairly quickly. I think the bigger thing I'd be worried about is if there is any debris which may have been in the fuel lines. Hopefully none of it will have gotten to the injectors/injector pump. Since I don't have a definitive answer for you, I'm leaving it hear as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out I made the rookie error of putting the fuel lines on the wrong connectors on the fuel filter.

I swapped the blue and white around and the car is now running great.